# synchronous .each with asynchronous .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm breaking my head reading all of the other questions about this subject, but can't seem to find the best option for my code. Basically I have a `.each` iterator that does an asynchronous ajax function. I need this to be synchronous without locking the browsers so I opted for not using `async: false`.

Here's the code:

```
$(".btn-timbrar").each(function(i, obj){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Home?opt=Recibo_G", 
        data: {id: $(obj).data("id"), p: pago},
        success: function(response){
            progress = progress + interval;
            $barra.find("#progreso-global").width(progress);
            $barra.find("#progreso-global").html(progress+"%"); 
            if(response.indexOf("timbrado con exito") != -1){               
                $(obj).parent().html('<a title="PDF" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini" target="_blank" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=PDF&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> PDF</a> <a title="XML" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini" target="_blank" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=XML&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> XML</a> <a title="Enviar Correo" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini btn-correo" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=Correo&='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a> <a title="Cancelar" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini btn-correo" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=Cancelar&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>');
                $("#example thead th:eq(5)").width(150);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why does it need to be synchronous? By definition, synchronous operations "lock" the current thread, so a non-blocking synchronous operation does not exist. You should use jQuery promises to ensure that some action gets taken once all AJAX requests complete

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. So why do you need this to be synchronous? Why not set a script server side which will handle all datas at once, using then only one ajax call? Isn't your issue just because of `obj` in success callback? If ya, use any kind of closure, e.g, use option context of ajax request set to `obj` then use `this` inside success callback

Comment: Q. Do you need the Ajax requests to run sequentially or all in parallel?

Comment: I need them to run sequentially, running them server side is my alternative approach but I rather try this first.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without using `async: false` is to resort to callbacks instead of an `.each()` loop. For instance:

```
var buttons = $(".btn-timbrar");

(function nextButton() {
    var obj = [].pop.call(buttons);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Home?opt=Recibo_G", 
        data: {id: $(obj).data("id"), p: pago},
        success: function(response){
            progress = progress + interval;
            $barra.find("#progreso-global").width(progress);
            $barra.find("#progreso-global").html(progress+"%"); 
            if(response.indexOf("timbrado con exito") != -1){               
                $(obj).parent().html('<a title="PDF" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini" target="_blank" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=PDF&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> PDF</a> <a title="XML" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini" target="_blank" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=XML&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> XML</a> <a title="Enviar Correo" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini btn-correo" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=Correo&='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a> <a title="Cancelar" class="btn btn-recibo-info btn-mini btn-correo" href="/ReciboVital/Home?opt=Cancelar&id='+$(obj).data("id")+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>');
                $("#example thead th:eq(5)").width(150);
            }
            if(buttons.length > 0) { 
                nextButton();
            }
        }
    });
})();
```